# Filtering rows in Azure Synapse/Data Factory dataflow

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I have been stuck for a bit trying to sort this out and for some reason it is not working.

I am reading a parquet file on a Pipeline in Synapse, after that I am selecting the columns I want to keep and before doing the sink, I want to add a filter (WHERE clause in SQL) to only keep specific rows.Here is the set up

[Set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnbTz.png)

Currently if I do a Data preview of the SelectColumns output I get data just fine.

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAGCH.png)

And here is the definition of my filter

[filter definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQb2c.png)

But if I check the Data Preview for the filter task, it says no doutput data.

Can someone help me finding out whats going on please? I even tried a simpler filter SCTSTCO=='ABCD' just for testing and the same.

Am I just being too dumb?

Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above expression is working fine for me.

[image]

The expression `CTSOCO=='ABCD' || CTSOCO=='ACRF'` also working fine in the filter transformation.

If your data preview is resulting no rows, you might need to refresh the dataflow debug here.

[image]

Comment: I don't think so. whatever might be file type, as per the input data preview, it should give required output.

Comment: Hi @Rakesh, thanks a lot for your explanation.

That is exactly what I did, both with the IN function or just testing with ==. Pretty much the design you have there is exactly the same one that I have (please check the images I attached, for some reason you need to click on them, they are not showing directly)

Could it not be working for me due to some type of configuration error?

Many thanks

Comment: I have also reset the Data flow debug by turnting it off yesterday and just turned it back on and still no data coming out. I even tried the conditional split way to get rows you can do and still nothing. I am really at a loss here :S

Comment: I think by looking at your issue, its better to raise a support ticket because these kind of issues are not related to your input data or output data. This seems to an internal issue.

Comment: Thanks Rakesh, do they actually reply to tickets like this? I am afraid to raise a ticket and them telling me I am just being dumb in my dessing and that I am missing something.

Comment: No, They will reply.

Comment: Last question Rakesh, how do I open a ticket regarding this specific dataflow?

Comment: Also, do I need a support plan for that ticket, as I don´t have one.

Comment: Follow these steps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request

Comment: Thanks for all your support. I didn´t end up raising a ticket as I found there was an issue with the data with damn trailing spaces. I had already checked for it and it seemed fine but for some reason I missed it. Many thanks and it is working just fine as I originally design it which was pretty much the same answer you gave